# JS Timezone wrong offset

Tags: javascript, timezone, utc, date-fns

Alright, so I know date & timezones is basically hell in JS, but I can't figure this out:

I have a string which is a RFC3339 date representation: `2020-03-13T19:30:00Z`

I'm in Paris, (UTC+2) so you would expect the LocaleString to be 2020-03-13 21:30:00, but it shows up as 2020-03-13T20:30:00.

Am I missing something ?

PS: I'm using the `date-fns` library, here is the example code:

```
    const value = '2020-03-13T19:30:00Z';

    console.log(value);
    console.log(utcToZonedTime(value, 'Europe/Paris').toLocaleString());
```

Comment: 2020-03-13 was CET (UTC+1), the switch to CEST has been on 2020-03-29.

Comment: Oh right @Andreas that makes sense, let me run a few tests but I think thats it

Answer (score 0):

As @Andreas said:

> 2020-03-13 was CET (UTC+1), the switch to CEST has been on 2020-03-29.